# Shrink navbar AFTER cover image

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I'm building a website from scratch using Bootstrap 4. The idea is to have a full screen cover image with a 'fixed in place' transparent navbar at the top; this part is easy and I can pretty much do it with my eyes closed. What I'm trying to now achieve is an effect so when the user scrolls down and hits the end of the cover image, the navbar will shrink down and be sticky at the top.

I've found so many tutorials and guides that teach how to do this in Jquery however they all offer basically the code which is to make it shrink after 'so many pixels' (in the case of the example below its 50). I like the idea of the Jquery adding in a class and then removing the class, however I'm not sure how I can modify so it activates when it hits the bottom of my cover image rather than the 50px.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('nav').addClass('shrink');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
  }
});
```

Comment: Try to get the bottom position of the cover image and change your code accordingly.

Comment: @camelsWriteInCamelCase Errr I don't think that's the best way to do it.. My cover image stretches to the size of your display... So everyone is going to have a different bottom position (depending on their screen resolution).

Comment: @user3599852 Just get the height of your image, and if you reach the "height" in pixel it means you reach it's bottom (depending of the case, you might want to add the height of the navbar)

Comment: @Kangouroops Like I said to the person above who suggested the same thing. This is not a good solution because the image is set to cover the whole screen so the height of the image will stretch depending on your screen display. That means everyone will have a different image height depending on the resolution of their screen.

Comment: @user3599852 That's why you get the height with javascript. I'm not talking about the height of the original picture but the height of the rendered picture. It could be on window.load...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the height of your rendered image thanks to jquery.

Then, you simply change the offset parameter. Here is a pen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KyQddz

```
<div class="navbar">
  This is my navbar
</div>
<figure>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x80" />  
</figure>



* {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.navbar {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;  
}
.shrink {
  background: green;
}
figure {
  height: 2000px;
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

var imgHeight;

$(window).on('load', function () {
  imgHeight = $('img').height();
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > imgHeight) {
    $('.navbar').addClass('shrink');
  } else {
    $('.navbar').removeClass('shrink');
  }
});
```

If you want the navbar the be fixed only after you scroll the height of the image, just move `position:fixed;top:0;` to the `.shrink` class.

```
.navbar {
      background: red;
      width: 100%;
      height: 60px; 
    }
    .shrink {
      background: green;
      position: fixed;
      top:0;
     }
```

Comment: this is perfect! Thank you, I have marked you as the best answer. Could I possibly bother you for one more thing? Is it possible to make the navbar fixed in position at the top so as you're scrolling down it doesnt move over the image? I kind of want it to be fixed and then become sticky once it hits the bottom of the image.

Comment: @user3599852 You don't bother me, don't worry. Do you mean, the navbar not sticky and as soon as you reach the bottom of the image, it becomes sticky ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help so far! It might be easier if I just show you an example - https://cameronjhurley.com/ - You'll notice how on this website the menu is fixed in position at the top of the cover image and then once you scroll down and past the image, The navbar shrinks down and becomes sticky to the rest of the website. I think I know how to do it with Bootstrap but I guess I'm just asking for a second opinion haha..

Comment: Well, just move `position: fixed; top:0;` to the `.shrink` class.
I'll edit my answer

Comment: You're a legend, thank you so much for all your help! :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help ;)

Comment: Could I please possibly be a pain again? I have got everything setup exactly how I want it so far, the code you gave me, I managed to alter it and get it working exactly how I want it... However I cant for the life of me get a nice smooth transition to happen when I scroll down, it just looks so snappy and choppy, I'd literally be happy with anything that makes it look a little more smooth. I've literally spent hours trying to get something to work but no luck.. I made a pen of my whole project so far - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/POQeVK (I'm so sorry for the messy code).

Comment: @user3599852 Well, that's tricky because you can't have a transition betweek `position: relative` and `position: fixed;`. You could play with a third class that you'll fire between the first state and the second state, please take a look : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XzZYLp

Comment: I altered it and it works perfectly, what an awesome little trick haha! Thank you once again! ONE LAST THING (I'm so sorry haha.. As a positive you are teaching me a lot here)... When you scroll back up and it hits the cover again, the nav continues to scroll up too.. Is there anyway to clean that up so when you scroll back up the navbar goes back into position at the top? - I'm trying to totally avoid the navbar colliding with the text I have on the cover image.

Comment: Actually don't worry! I've just added the css and it looks fine regardless! Thank you so much for all your help! :)